# Getting incorrect paths in Restangular. What am I doing wrong?

Tags: angularjs, restangular

Here is a miniature proof of concept. It fetches thing #100 and then saves it.

```
var things = ThingsAPI.all("things");
things.one(100).get()
.then(function(thing) {
  thing.put();
})
```

First it makes a GET request to

```
http://localhost:8080/things/100
```

but after that it PUTs to

```
http://localhost:8080/things/100/100
```

I would expect it to PUT to the same URL it came from, instead it's treating the url `http://localhost:8080/things/100` as a list and then trying to find entity `100` within it.

I just want this to PUT back to `http://localhost:8080/things/100`. What am I doing wrong?

EDIT:

If I fetch with this instead, the `PUT`ting works. But I would have expected to be able to do this with the `all` method.

```
ThingsAPI.one('things', 100).get()
```

And, for clarity, here is where I define `ThingsAPI`.

```
app.factory('ThingsAPI', function(Restangular) {
  return Restangular.withConfig(function(RestangularConfigurer) {
            RestangularConfigurer.setBaseUrl('http://localhost:8080/');
  });
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason is that you are treating the `100` as a nested resource for `things`. Therefore Restangular will generate routes as if `http://localhost:8080/things/100` is the index route for the resource named `100` -- although it actually is the show route for `things` resource with id `100`. These routes just accidentally happen to have the same URI.

As you can see, Restangular has misunderstood your intented resource definiton, and eg. `PUT` will generate an incorrect route.

Treating `100` as an identifier for `things` resource will correct the issue, as you seem to have found out:  `ThingsAPI.one('things', 100).get()`

This translates to `one(resource, identifier).get()`.

Comment: I ecountered the same problem today. Good to see the answer, however what I was going to do was something similar to this: https://github.com/angular-app/angular-app/blob/master/client/src/common/resources/projects.js I only wanted to substitute var Projects = $mongolabResource('projects'); with var Projects = Restangular.all('projects');. Seems that I can't do that. So how can I create a restangular resource that I will be able to decorate with some utility methods? I can't use "one" in the service because I don't know object id yet.

Comment: Seems that it's possible to use get instead of one: var things = ThingsAPI.all("things");
things.get(100)
.then(function(thing) {
  thing.put();
})

Comment: Please create a new question for what you are trying to accomplish, and I will try to answer it. Thx :)